# SAML/OpenID authentication on Docker/Core OS

Tags: docker, single-sign-on, openid, kubernetes

I have a set of servers running Core OS/Docker/Docker Swarm.

I have my users in a SAML/OpenID SSO server. I want these users to be able to
run Docker containers on my Core OS cluster.

How do I authenticate SAML/OpenID users into Docker/Docker Swarm? Is there a PlugIn for that?  If I add Kubernetes, does Kubernetes have SAML/OpenID authentication?